# Is there a way to process this code fast and what is the error of this code?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, parallel-processing, cpu

I have a code to character replacing and I can't figure out what is the error of this code? Is there a way to process this code faster with something like dedicating several cpu cores for this script?

```
#!/bin/bash

startdirectory="/data/test/cpy"
searchterm="""
replaceterm=""


i=0; 

for file in $(grep -l -R $searchterm $startdirectory)
    do
      cp $file $file.bak
      sed -e s/$searchterm/$replaceterm/ig $file > tempfile.tmp
      mv tempfile.tmp $file
      let i++;

    done
```

Comment: probably you have tripple quotes in defining variable `searchterm`. I think you need to escape one quote, just try to write: `"\""`

Comment: Unless the processing you are doing is crazily intense, and from what you post it isn't, then dedicating several CPU cores to the task (not an easy thing to do) will just overload the I/O channels from disk to RAM - unless you have parallel to the metal file access.  Do you ?

Comment: can you explain please if $searchterm suppose to be empty , or contains a single double-quotes ? if empty , than it seems that your code can be simplify to ...rm -rf $startdirectory... if you want to remove all double-queates from all the files , than you just need to add slash , searchterm="/""

Comment: Since this executes sequentially it took a lot of time. I tried to run parallelly and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct way to do this.
Unless the processing you are doing is crazily intense, and from what you post it isn't, then dedicating several CPU cores to the task (not an easy thing to do) will just overload the I/O channels from disk to RAM - unless you have parallel to the metal file access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this executes sequentially it took a lot of time. I tried to run parallelly as chunks and it worked. Thanks.

Unless the processing you are doing is crazily intense, and from what you post it isn't, then dedicating several CPU cores to the task (not an easy thing to do) will just overload the I/O channels from disk to RAM - unless you have parallel to the metal file access. This answer was really helpful

Comment: If you want to speed things up, use a language where you don't have to fork spawn `cp`, `sed` and `mv`.